# How to pass in '$' to a Web API call from powershell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call my API via powershell:

```
localhost/myApi/action/param1/$param2/param3
```

The $ sign in $param2 is causing the call to fail. Powershell can't find the Action when I do that. However if the parameter doesn't have a dollar sign in it, it works fine. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried `localhost/myApi/action/param1/%24param2/param3`? %24 is the escape code for $

Comment: What if you URL-encode the '$' character (i.e., replace it with '%24')? Web API parameter binding should automatically URL-decode strings passed as path variables or querystring parameters... but I've never tried invoking an action from Powershell.

Comment: Just ran into some global.asax access issue. Trying to fix that, so I can try this solution. Will update

Comment: This worked. Can you post it as the answer? I'll mark it as correct @RonBeyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your HTML codes, I'm not very familiar with PowerShell, but there is a built-in C# library to help you: [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx)

So for your example, you should be encoding your URL to `localhost/myApi/action/param1/%24param2/param3` since %24 is the URL escape code for `$`.